# How to fetch all activity related to an event

Tags: php, mysql, orm, yii

I have a site having an event concept where images, comment and status can be added to a event .I have a event timeline which will show above three activities sorted by created time. Database schema is as follows.[image: schema]

How can i sort all data by date?

Comment: Can you give us a sample of your expected output?

Comment: Actually i want to show activities to a particular event as Facebook timeline does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I don't know what is your expected output, I will assume that this is what you want

```
(SELECT event_id, created, 'Photo' AS description FROM tbl_gallery_photo)
UNION
(SELECT event_id, created, 'Comment' AS description FROM tbl_event_comment)
UNION
(SELECT event_id, create_time AS created, 'Status' AS description FROM tbl_event_status)
ORDER BY created DESC
```

Comment: Can i set a flag to check whether the row is from comment,photo or from Status As i have to display these activities in different format

Comment: Actually, I have included flag as a description, but you can change to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Now,you can create a view use the same fields, for excample, "created" and "event_id".
Then you can sort all data by date ,and join others tables.

Comment: can you please elaborate more?